# Need help finding a replacement regulator

Tags: voltage-regulator

[image: Voltage Regulator]

Im trying to find a replacement for the low dropout voltage regulator shown in the pic, im located in the U.S.(Florida). All help appreciated.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is both on repair (see http://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and shows no prior effort or research.

Comment: So buy one - they are commonly available.

Comment: Available one off from Disgikey in stock [**here**](http://www.digikey.com/product-search/en?FV=fff40027%2Cfff80182%2C40203a&k=ld1117&mnonly=0&newproducts=0&ColumnSort=1000011&page=1&stock=0&pbfree=0&rohs=0&quantity=1&ptm=0&fid=0&pageSize=25) **BUT** there are several options - yours appears to be a 5V version based on the 50xxx text BUT may not be. They come in either fixed voltage versions (1.8 2.5 3V3, 5V) and a 1.25V version designed to be scaled up to any voltage up t0 15v (using 2 resistors)....

Comment: ...  Here is a TO220 pkg (like yours) [5V version](http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/LD1117V50/497-7311-5-ND/1663515) 66c in 1's in stock!

Comment: Here is a [3v3 version](http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/LD1117V33/497-1491-5-ND/586012) and here is a [1.25V version intended for "adjustable" use](http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/LD1117V-DG/497-12926-ND/3083462)  There are nominally 800 mA versions (most) and 1A from a few makers  but progbably not much difference. FWIW Digikey are awesome - same day shipping up until (I think) 8pm !!!!, shipping will cost you more than the part. Look at the site and but some other stuff too. [My only relationship with Digikey is as a happy customer](http://bit.ly/OldGreyGuy)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the markings and [datasheet for the LD1117A](http://www.protostack.com/download/LD1117_A.pdf) here are the specs:

- Output voltage: 5 V
- Max input voltage: 18 V
- Max output current: 1 A
- Dropout voltage (1 A): 1.3 V
- Package: TO-220
- Pin configuration: Ground-Output-Input (GOI) from left to right

The problem is the pin configuration. A lot of TO-220 LDO regulators use the Input-Ground-Output (IGO) order. You'll have to find one with the same GOI order as the original.

A quick search on mouser yields only one suitable part with the GOI order: [LM1086-5.0](http://www2.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Texas-Instruments/LM1086IT-50-NOPB).

If you can't get one with the GOI pin order you could try to connect the pins with insulated wire to the right pads.

Comment: Yea, I may need to configure a IGO, was hoping to find a GOI near by but couldn't come up with any hits near my location.http://comingsoon.radioshack.com/-5v-fixed-voltage-regulator-7805/2761770.html#.VbX6avlVhBc

Comment: That 7805 is not a low-dropout regulator.